# On screen display (OSD) linux utilty that works with X11 and accepts vector (.ttf, .otf) etc. fonts?

Tags: x11

Is anybody aware of such a CLI tool that could be invoked from a script in order to display text on the root window of an X11 display?

I know of an xosd-bind package available from most linux distros that provides this functionality via the osd_cat command which is (e.g.) invoked like so:

```
echo $PATH | osd_cat -p middle -A center -s 1 -S white -c red -O 1 -u blue -d 10 -f '-xos4-terminus-bold-r-normal-*-32-320-*-*-*-*-iso10646-1'
```

Unfortunately this command only appears to accept bitmap fonts and the largest fonts I have found are quite small on current hardware in my case a 15" 1920x1200 display.

Apart from the font's family & size the utility would take as input the position of the text on the display and such stuff as the font color… outline… etc. Pretty much like osd_cat as a matter of fact.

An unofficial script that I could hack to my requirements would be fine.